# .htaccess Clean Url with multiple parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm a newbie in php and htaccess, and this is my first post. I have a problem in my URL, i just wanted to make it clean. By the way, the URL that I have now is

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?page=home&lesson=1.1
```

how can i change it to

```
http://www.example.com/home/1.1/
```

and here is my `index.php` code

```
<?php
    include("page_check.php"); // this is where the program check what is the requested page. 
    include($page); // it could be home.php, login.php and etc
    include("templates/layout.php"); //the template, contains HTML tags...
?>
```

`page_check.php` code...

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    $array_page=array('home','create_group','group','try_it_out','logout');
    $page_no_session=array('login','register','email_confirmation');
    $len;
    if (!empty($_SESSION['login_state'])){
        $len = count($page_no_session);
        for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
            if ($page_no_session[$i] == $page){
                $page = "home";
            }
        }
        if(empty($page)){
            $page = "home";
        }
    }
    else{
        if(empty($page) AND empty($_SESSION['login_state'])){
            $page = "login";
        }
        else{
            $len = count($array_page);
            for($i = 0;$i < $len;$i++){
                if ($array_page[$i] == $page){
                $page = "login";
                }
            }
        }
    }
        $page = "$page.php"; //this is what I'm telling, it could be home.php, login.php and etc.. defends upon the requested php file
?>
```

By the way guys. I want my URL to look nice and clean and I want also to ask for your advice what other things I can do to make my website more secure. I hope someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&lesson=$2 [L,QSA]
```